# SQL Many-to-many relationship in 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would appreciate some help with SQL.

Problem:

There are 2 tables - Homes and Owners.

Homes:

| ID | Name | Address | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | home1 | Street1 | Type1 |
| 2 | home2 | Street2 | Type2 |

Owners:

| ID_home | Name | Ocupation | Sallary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BOB | Builder | 6942 |
| 2 | Jorge | Singer | 500 |
| 2 | Mike | Artist | 1000 |

Houses can be owned by multiple owners and owners can have multiple homes. Id is a unique identificator for each home and it corresponds in both tables.

How would I write a query that would **only** return homes (and respective owners) that have more than 1 owner.

The expected result in this case would be:

| ID | Name | Address | Type | Name | Ocupation | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | home2 | Street2 | Type2 | Jorge | Singer | 500 |
| 2 | home2 | Street2 | Type2 | Mike | Artist | 1000 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If houses are owned by multipled owners, and owners can have multiple homes, there is a many to many table missing in your data model (if you want to have it normalized)

Comment: Your data model is not a many-to-many, but a many-to-one actually. How would you represent an owner that has two houses for example?

Comment: @Alejandro repeating the data. It's possible but not normalized (and for sure not recommended), as I said in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Just with this simple query you can get what you want

```
select *
from owners o
  join homes h
    on h.ID = o.ID_home
where Id_home in ( 
  select o.Id_home
  from owners o
  group by o.Id_home
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

The subselect returns the home identifier for those which appear more than once in `owners` table.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a many-to-many relationship between these two tables you need to create another table "Home_Owners" (otherwise you have just one-to-many relationship):

| Home_id | Owner_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

So, now you can have multiple owners for one house and multiple houses with one owner. Also you shouldn’t state "ID_home" in "Owners" table like you did.

Then your SQL script could look like:

```
SELECT * FROM owners
LEFT JOIN home_owners ON home_owners.owner_id = owner.id
LEFT JOIN homes ON home_owners.home_id = home.id
WHERE owners.id IN
(SELECT owners.id FROM home_owners GROUP BY owners.id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```